# Tor Browser already running when trying to start the tor browser on Windows

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

When starting the Tor Browser I get a message stating:

`Tor Browser is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Tor Browser process, or restart your system`

I tried looking for tor.exe and firefox.exe in the process manager but there where not running.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that in the Windows Security panel under Virus & threat protection Ransomware protection was enabled. This protects files, folders and memory areas from unauthorized changes. The solution is to click on 'Manage ransomware protection' and click Allow an app through controlled folder access.

Comment: This is a known issue and one of the first things we ask when people have issue with Windows. Until Windows malware scanners stops seeing Tor Browser as malware, nothing can be done except to manually check it.